# Fragments based menu

Tags: android, android-layout

I would like to create a static menu. I mean during compilation I'll know exactly what items are supposed to be there and I'd like to create it using the designer. I'm considering using 2 approaches:

- `ListView`
- `ScrollView`

In both cases I'd like to fill it with some instances of a `Fragment` or maybe something more suitable (I don't know if something like this exists - please tell me it does)

This `Fragment` wouldn't be very complicated, but still it'll be something more than just a line of text. (icon, background, text, maybe something more)

In another app I've already created a `ListView` using fragments, adapters which was dynamically created while the app was running. In this case though such an approach doesn't seem to be the best one.

So firstly can this be done statically with the designer?

Secondly, which view would you recommend, `ListView` or `ScrollView`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So firstly can this be done statically with the designer?

If by "this" you mean use `ListView`, `ScrollView`, `Fragment`, icon, background, and text, then generally yes.

> Secondly, which view would you recommend, ListView or ScrollView?

Neither. Use one of the following:

- Have your application open up on some primary activity (not a menu, but one of the things you would have put in the menu), where the rest of the features are accessed via the action bar (using ActionBarSherlock for backwards-compatibility)
- If there is no obvious "primary" activity to open on, have your application open up on a [dashboard](http://www.androiduipatterns.com/2011/02/ui-design-pattern-dashboard.html), perhaps using [this layout manager class](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/source/browse/android/src/com/google/android/apps/iosched/ui/widget/DashboardLayout.java), using the action bar for navigation in your "interior" activities